# Extract 'type of' relations from Freebase

Tags: types, freebase

I have downloaded the Freebase dump from  https://developers.google.com/freebase/data?hl=en, and I want to extract 'type of' or 'IS A' relations from it(e.g. C++ IS A programming language).

Is there a list of relations which are these type?